# Unexpected result from Sum Over windowed function

Tags: sql, sql-server

This has been driving me crazy, any help is much appreciated. Code and results below - my question is simple. On the results line 4, the Activity does NOT match lag_Activity, why does the group number not increase?

```
create table #exampleTable 
    (name varchar(20)
    ,pnum bigint
    ,activity varchar(10)
    ,startTime datetime
    ,endTime datetime)
insert into #exampleTable
values 
    ('Harry Potter',12345678, 'On Shift', '2022-05-18 13:00:00', '2022-05-18 22:00:00')
    ,('Harry Potter',12345678,'Off Shift','2022-05-18 16:30:00','2022-05-18 17:30:00')
    ,('Jane Doe',98765432,'Off Shift','2022-05-18 02:00:00','2022-05-18 05:00:00')
    ,('Jane Doe',98765432,'On Shift','2022-05-18 02:00:00','2022-05-18 16:00:00')
    ,('Jane Doe',98765432,'Off Shift','2022-05-18 06:15:00','2022-05-18 06:45:00')
    ,('Jane Doe',98765432,'Off Shift','2022-05-18 11:30:00','2022-05-18 12:00:00')
    ,('Jane Doe',98765432,'Off Shift','2022-05-18 12:00:00','2022-05-18 15:50:00')

select 
    sum(case when activity = lag_activity and starttime <= lag_endtime then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by pnum order by pnum, starttime) as grp
    ,*
from (
    select 
        *
        ,lag(endtime) over(order by pnum, starttime) lag_endtime
        ,lag(activity)  over(order by pnum, starttime) lag_activity
    from #exampleTable
        where endtime-Starttime>0
    ) a
order by pnum, starttime
```

Here are the results:

```
grp name            pnum        activity    lag_activity    startTime               endTime                 lag_endtime
1   Harry Potter    12345678    On Shift    NULL            2022-05-18 13:00:00.000 2022-05-18 22:00:00.000 NULL
2   Harry Potter    12345678    Off Shift   On Shift        2022-05-18 16:30:00.000 2022-05-18 17:30:00.000 2022-05-18 22:00:00.000
1   Jane Doe        98765432    Off Shift   Off Shift       2022-05-18 02:00:00.000 2022-05-18 05:00:00.000 2022-05-18 17:30:00.000
1   Jane Doe        98765432    On Shift    Off Shift       2022-05-18 02:00:00.000 2022-05-18 16:00:00.000 2022-05-18 05:00:00.000
2   Jane Doe        98765432    Off Shift   On Shift        2022-05-18 06:15:00.000 2022-05-18 06:45:00.000 2022-05-18 16:00:00.000
3   Jane Doe        98765432    Off Shift   Off Shift       2022-05-18 11:30:00.000 2022-05-18 12:00:00.000 2022-05-18 06:45:00.000
3   Jane Doe        98765432    Off Shift   Off Shift       2022-05-18 12:00:00.000 2022-05-18 15:50:00.000 2022-05-18 12:00:00.000
```

Comment: Posting query plans may help, but there is a broader issue here from what I can infer from your question.  You are assuming ordering semantics over columns not included in your order bys in your OVER clauses.  There is no guarantee of order on fields like activity even if you happen to be getting the values you think you want there right now.  The optimizer can pick different plans and potentially faster ones that don't know or care about the input order you insert those rows into a temp table.  So, please describe what semantic output you want and maybe people can help you better.

Comment: Thanks @ConorCunninghamMSFT, adding additional columns to the ordering fixed the issue - though I still don't fully understand how the function is doing the sum. In one of my tests, the group number increased by 2, which seems like it shouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ConorCunninghamMSFT for the tip, the lag functions and Sum Over function needed additional ordering. The order itself is less important than the fact that it stays consistent.

```
select 
    sum(case when activity = lag_activity and starttime <= lag_endtime then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by pnum order by pnum, starttime, endtime) as grp
    ,*
from (
    select 
        *
        ,lag(endtime) over(order by pnum, starttime, endtime) lag_endtime
        ,lag(activity)  over(order by pnum, starttime, endtime) lag_activity
    from #exampleTable
        where endtime-Starttime>0
    ) a
order by pnum, starttime, endtime
```